# Desabilitar / Habilitar componentes quando tiver alterando

Tags: angular

Tenho esta variável **alterarRegistro : boolean;**.

neste metodo **ngOnInit()**, verifico se é alteração ou não

> ```
>   ngOnInit() {
>       this.empresa = new Empresa;
>       if(this.routaAtual.snapshot.url.length > 1){
>         let id = this.routaAtual.snapshot.url[1].path;
>         this.alterarRegistro = true;
>       } else {
>         this.alterarRegistro = false;
>         this.titulo = "Cadastrar banco";
>       }
>     }
> ```

Quero que alguns componentes sejam inativos quando a variável **this.alterarRegistro** for **true**.

Não consegui fazer com a opção **disabled**.

Como proceder então ?

Comment: Dentro do componente no HTML... [disabled]="!alterarRegistro"

Comment: tem como postar o html desse componente?